# Xdvi crashes when used with Emacs with I/O correlation

Tags: latex, emacs, crash, dvi

I use Emacs 24 to process LaTeX files. When I enable I/O correlation, Xdvi crashes within a second after launch. Apparently this [is caused by a bug in libfreetype](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=733894).

So, my question is, is there any workaround for this problem?

As a side note, there are ways to [use evince with I/O correlation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/setup-synctex-with-emacs) but I couldn't get them to work.